# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/time/LocalTime;

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-studio-2.1

I'm developing an app using Android Studio 2.1.2, API level 23.
In a class I used the `java.time.LocalTime` class, but at runtime an unhanded `NoClassDefFoundError` exception kills my activity. Googling, I understood that I have to add dependencies in build.gradle because Android classes are developed using a version of JDK older than Java 8 (when the `LocalTime` class has been added).

So I have to write something like: `compile "java.time:LocalTime:1.8"`

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

The Android runtime supports a limited subset of the standard library enhancements made in JDK 8. The JDK 8 date time library is not supported. You can use something like http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your API version on Emulator or Device. It works upper 26 version (starts from Oreo).